# Processing Object Manipulations

Tags: python, object, oop, animation, processing

I have a question about objects in Processing. Processing or Processing Py, they are pretty much the same.

Here it goes: how do we manipulate/move/erase objects?

Let's imagine a moving circle. It moves on the X axis, because we increment the X value of its center point. But while doing that, it leaves a trace of all other circles drawn previously. Now, we can add a background command right before drawing a new circle, that would hide the trace, and in a way it does the trick.

```
x = 0 

def setup():
    size(800, 800)
    
def draw():
    global x
    background(255, 255, 255)
    circle(x, 400, 50)
    x += 5
```

I also tried the OOP approach, creating a class, that can create a circle as a method. But since it's not like prefabs in Unity, I can't really access the circle once it's drawn. So if I want to move it, I have to redraw the background and then call the method again to draw a new circle. As a result it's the same technique.

```
class moveCircle(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, r):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.r = r
        
    def makeCircle(self):
        circle(self.x, self.y, self.r)

x = 0

def setup():
    size(800, 800)
        
def draw():
    global x
    background(150, 150, 150)
    a = moveCircle(x, 400, 50)
    a.makeCircle()
    x += 5
```

- So, my point is, isn't there a proper way to manipulate objects? Like if I want to move the circle, can I somehow just change its coordinates instead of redrawing all those layers?
- And if not, does it mean that if a have, say, 3 circles and only one of them moves, the other two need to be redrawn just as well, but on the same unchanged position?

Answer (score 2):

The following Processing source code demonstrates one technique using a PVector array to keep track of x and y coordinates of multiple rectangles.  An object class could also be used for this purpose.  To run the demo first select the object that you want to move and then use the keyboard arrow keys to relocate it.

```
PVector[] r;
int selected = -1;

void setup() {
  surface.setTitle("Move selected rectangle with keyboard arrows");
  size(600, 400);
  r = new PVector[3];
  // init values
  r[0] = new PVector(140, 20);
  r[1] = new PVector(25, 50); 
  r[2] = new PVector(180,100);
}

void draw() {
  background(209);
  for(int i = 0; i < r.length; i++){
    if(i == selected){
      fill(0, 255, 0);
    } else {
      fill(209);
    }
  rect(r[i].x, r[i].y, 50, 50);
  }
}

void mousePressed(){
  for(int i = 0; i < r.length; i++){
    if((mouseX >= r[i].x) && (mouseX <= r[i].x + 50) && (mouseY >= r[i].y) && (mouseY <= r[i].y + 50)) {
    selected = i;
    println("selected =",selected);  
  }
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (key == CODED) {
    if (keyCode == LEFT) {
     r[selected].x-=5;
    }
    if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
      r[selected].x+=5;
    }
    if (keyCode == UP) {
      r[selected].y-=5;
    }
    if (keyCode == DOWN) {
      r[selected].y+=5;
    }
  }
}
```